# Use google login to get permission to access users calendar from .net core

Tags: .net, .net-core, google-api-dotnet-client

I am creating a simple MVC project for some clients.  I have about 100 clients that use my simple scheduling software that is specific to their industry.  I store the events/appointments in a local database and display them when they log in to the system.  They can do CRUD operations on the calendar.  Now they are requesting that I sync with their google calendars so they can create events/appointments in google (while in the field away form the application) and have them show in the program as well as show their events/appointments in their google calendar they created in the software while in the field.

I need to allow them to log in with their google account, grant access to the their calendar on behalf of my program and then do the sync.  The authorization credentials in all the examples show a client-login and client-secret to log in. How do I get that from the user after their login?  I'm confused on how this whole operation works.

Thanks.

Comment: The client ID and client secret are ones that *you* set up - they're about your software, not about the user. See if https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth helps you.